# Update Existing Outlook Calendar Appointment

Tags: c#, outlook, icalendar, vcalendar

I am implementing an application that manages meetings. As one of the feature, it can send a meeting request to Outlook.

The problem is, that when the meeting is updated, the message sent, does not update Outlook calendar. I am using MS Outlook 2003.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong.

I implemented the meeting request according to [sending-meeting-requests](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/sending-meeting-requests-to-outlook-via-aspnet-mail-message/)
 .

When sending the request I change some fields as required by [rfc2446](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2446.txt).

Below is a combination of two messages.

1. Lines appearing only in meeting creation
2. Lines appearing only in meeting update – which does not work.

Other lines appears in both messages.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Attendee One;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:komerciala@email.eu
ATTENDEE;CN=User Super;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION
 ;CUTYPE=ORGANIZER;ORGANIZER=:MAILTO:master@email.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
COMMENT:
1. CREATED:20120905T151819
2. CREATED:20120905T151945
DESCRIPTION:
1. DTEND:20120905T163000
2. DTEND:20120906T163000
1. DTSTAMP:20120905T151819
2. DTSTAMP:20120905T151945
1. DTSTART:20120905T160000
2. DTSTART:20120906T160000
1. LAST-MODIFIED:20120905T151819
2. LAST-MODIFIED:20120905T151945
LOCATION:LJUBLJANA\, CESTA V MESTNI LOG   55
ORGANIZER;CN=User Super:MAILTO:master@email.com
PRIORITY:5
1. SEQUENCE:0
2. SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:kioliko
UID:5c6beaaf-1479-4028-b813-b9a66a2e3640
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:Display
TRIGGER:-P1D
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thank you!